# IdenityServer4 doubts on IdentityResource, usercalims

Tags: identityserver4

I have doubt on Identity Resource user claims

I have configured as below
**Scenario-1**

identity resource ("family") --> user claims as [ "kid1", "kid2", "wife"]

**Q1**: as per the documentation "List of associated user claim types that should be included in the identity token." But I cant see this in identity token?

Scenario-2

**IS configuration**

identity resource ("family" ) --> user claims [ "kid1", "kid2", "wife"]

API Scope (api1) --> user claims ["role"]
API Scope (api2) --> user claims ["country", "address"]

API Resource (TestAPI2Test) --> API Scopes [ "api1", "api2"] AND user claims ["role", "wife"]
API Resource (TestAPI1) --> API Scopes [ "api1", "api2"] AND user claims ["role", "siblings", "wife"]
API Resource (testResource) --> API Scopes [ "api2"] AND user claims ["role", "siblings", "kid1", "name" ]

**Angular Client Configuration**
requested scopes: [openid profile api1 offline_access family]

**access_token**

```
"aud": [
"TestAPI1",
"TestAPI2Test",
"https://localhost:5001/resources"
],
"idp": "local",
"role": "admin",
"wife": "Sandra",
"sid": "BD5F4222976FFE2752168EFDE9391B2B",
"iat": 1621413193,
"scope": [
"openid",
"profile",
"api1",
"family",
"offline_access"
],
```

**Q2**: Why I can not see the identity resource user claims "kid1", "kid2" with the access_token?
**Q3**: I can see that only API Resource user claims only included in the access_token, Identity token user claims are retuned when requesting the user end point?

can you advise/clarify on Q1 , Q2 and Q3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can configure in the client configuration in IdentityServer if the claims should be included in the ID-Token or if they should be retrieved separately from the /UserInfo endpoint.

You set this using this flag:
AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true/false;

Only the userClaims added to the ApiScope and ApiResources will be included in the access token.

Claims/scopes added under the IdentityResource controls what ends up in the ID-token/UserInfo endpoint.

To complement this answer, I write a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic:
[IdentityServer – IdentityResource vs. ApiResource vs. ApiScope](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/02/identityserver-identityresource-vs-apiresource-vs-apiscope/)

Comment: Thanks Tore Nestenius for your answer, I already tried AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken but I doubt is that "List of associated user claim types that should be included in the identity token." meaning what? As I know identity token is id_token right? what I understand from my experience is identity resource userclaims means related to the login users claims. UserClaims related to the ApiScope and ApiResources are included in access_token and using for the APis. Means if you want to get the claim value from API you need to include in access_token

Comment: Yes, the API only get's the access token and inside it you have the user-claims. You can in theory in one of the event handlers, call IdentityServer UserInfo or token introspection endpoint using the access token to get more details about the access token and the user.

Comment: how to access the  token introspection endpoint? UserInfo can be accessed by passing access token but I am not sure about token introspection endpoints

Comment: you pass the access token to the introspection endpoint in the same way as userinfo, its main purpose is to allow api's to get the current current status of the access token (is active claim).